# My homegym workout doesn't allow me to add 1 rep at each set of my Military Seated Dumbells Press

Tags: bodybuilding, shoulders, overtraining, progress, overheadpress

I want to increase my reps on the Dumbells Seated OHP. But I can't. I even tend to regress (reps decrease) ; I eat a lot and I sleep well. I'm tired every day, I don't know why. You will find the reps I currently do, the weights, and my progression strategies below.

As I'm working out at home because of Coronavirus, I can't add weights so for a lot of exercizes, I just take short rest times.

My equipment is only: two dumbells, each has a max of 24kg. I can't do pull-ups (no equipment).

**My question is: how could I increase my reps at Db OHP?**

## Day 1: Push

1. **Dumbells Seated OHP** - rest: 2'30 - 24kg - Reps: 7 7 7 7 - Progression strategy: from work out to work out, 7 7 7 7 then 8 8 8 8 then 9 9 9 9 then 10 10 10 10, etc.
2. **Dumbells Chest Press** - rest: 1'30 - 24kg - Reps: 13 13 13 13 - Progression strategy: 13 13 13 13 then 13 13 13 14 then 13 13 14 14 then 13 14 14 14 then 14 14 14 14
3. **Dumbells Seated OHP** - rest: 1'30 - 12kg - Reps: 11 11 11 11 - Progression strategy: from work out to work out, 11 11 11 11 then 11 11 11 12, etc.
4. **Dumbells Chest Press** - rest: 1'30 - 24kg - Reps: 9 9 9 9 - Progression strategy: 9 9 9 9, then 9 9 9 10, then 9 9 10 10, etc.
5. **Dumbells Supination Curl** - rest: 1'30 - 12kg - Reps : 10 10 11 11 - Progression strategy: 10 10 11 11, then 10 11 11 11, then 11 11 11 11, etc.
6. **Hammer Curl** - rest: 1'30 - 12kg - Reps : 10 10 11 11 - Progression strategy: 10 10 11 11, then 10 11 11 11, then 11 11 11 11, etc.
7. **Lateral Dumbells Raises** - rest: 1'30 - 6kg - Reps : 17 17 17 17 - Progression strategy:  none

## Day 2: Pull

1. **Dumbells Unilateral Rowing** - rest: 1'30 - 28kg - Reps: 12 12 12 12 - Progression strategy: from work out to work out, 12 12 12 12 then 12 12 12 13 etc.
2. **Dumbells Unilateral Rowing** - rest: 1'30 - 28kg - Reps: 9 9 9 9 - Progression strategy: from work out to work out, 9 9 9 9 then 9 9 9 10 etc. - NB: yes, it's the same exercize again
3. **Dips on Bench** - rest: 1'30 - BodyWeight - Reps: 14 14 14 14 - Progression strategy: from work out to work out, 14 14 14 14 then 14 14 14 15 etc.
4. **Dips on Bench** - rest: 1'30 - BodyWeight - Reps: 14 14 14 14 - Progression strategy: from work out to work out, 14 14 14 14 then 14 14 14 15 etc. - NB: yes, it's the same exercize again
5. **Bird** - rest: 1'30 - 6kg - Reps: 14 14 14 14 - Progression strategy: none

## Day 3: Legs

1. **Glut Ham Raises** - rest: 1'30 - BodyWeight - Reps: 8 8 8 8 - Progression strategy: none (because I'm learning the exercize)
2. **Dumbells Calves** - rest: 1'30 - 24kg - Reps: 24 24 24 24 - Progression strategy: none
3. **Lateral Dumbells Raises** - Same as Day 1
4. **Bird** - Same as Day 2
5. Important: I was used to do Dumbells Squat and Dumbells Romanian DeadLift, but I have to stop it since 2 almost 3 weeks because I'm hurt...

Comment: What's the weekly schedule, particularly how many days between OHP? Why are dips on a pull day? And what happened when you tried my advice from your previous question?

Comment: Since I can do lots of rep except for my OHP, I don't take any rest day. Note that I can't increase my weights because I don't have the equipment :). Curls are in my push day and Dips kn my pull days because it allows me to have do better sets this way. Note that it doesn't seem to negatively affect the poly exercises of the next work out. Your advice was to increment little by little the reps, right?

Comment: Well as you can see I use your advice too,for the others exercises. For OHP I've used it for several weeks, it allowed me to go from 5 5 5 5 to 7 7 7 7. Do you think I should keep going on? Will it be useful to reach 16 16 16 16?

Comment: Couldn't hurt. Looks like just a blip. Somedays you feel like a million bucks, some days you can barely finish the warm-up sets. It evens out.

Comment: OK well I will try :)

Comment: @DaveLiepmann is it possible to do 3 sets of warm-up followed by only real 1 set, every day? I would increase by 1 rep each day. Do you think it's correct?

Comment: Never tried such an approach. Personally I like volume for the upper body, because it's so tricky to bet on exact rep expectations.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler - Still ignoring all the past suggestions to do Stronglifts or similar and stop creating questionable programs? You do 4 workouts that work the triceps with lots of reps on day 1, then another 2 on day two?  Stop it. You don't know enough yet to create an effective program. Go find an established beginner routine and follow it religiously for 6 months to a year.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd probably go with a 3 day full body workout, as this workout looks to be more of the advanced bodybuilder workout style. or do a 4 day workout and do two lower body days and two upper body days. either way..
Assuming your sleep and diet are fine, maybe your body has adapted to doing the OHP and its time to switch it up? you should switch exercises every 8-12 weeks.

I think you're overtraining, If I am reading this right you are doing 8 sets of dumbbell press and dumbbell chest press. I think you should do less sets and focus on more exercises. You can do a shoulder-focused workout that addresses weakness and try to do more over the week, but I think you should do 2 or 3 shoulder exercises, not just 8 sets of one. I also think instead of progressing one rep on each set(7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8), you should try just on the last set. For example, (7 7 7 7, 7 7 7 8, 7 7 7 9, 7 7 7 10)
Then roll back the other sets(7 7 7 10, 7 7 8 10, 7 7 10, 10). This is just an example, and you should just try to do as many as possible the very last set. I'd also suggest resting less. You should decrease the sets you do as you progress too.. for intake, 4x7 is 28, but 4x12 is 48, that's 20 more reps! try to stick to about 30 to 36 reps per exercise, and adjust the sets as needed. so if you are trying to do 15 reps, I would just do 2 sets.

so if I were to plan a workout for you it would look like this:

Day 1:

bench press (this works the shoulders too)

quads exercise

hips exercise

back exercise

shoulder-Arnold press

day 2:

incline press (this works the shoulders too, even more then the bench press)

quads exercise

hips exercise

lateral raise + rear deltoid raise

day 3:

close grip press(if you can't maybe a decline press)

quads exercise

hips exercise

dumbbell overhead press (rotate this out with a dumbbell front raise 
every workout cycle or every other week)

(rest 1 to 1.30 for each exercise.)
(phase 1, 5x5
phase 2, 4x8
phase 3 3x10
phase 4 3x12
phase 5 3x15
)
(work on increasing the last set by as many reps as you can each workout. one you hit a certain number, then roll back and try to get the second set to hit more and more reps each week. finally, then try to match the first set with the other sets, even if it takes a couple weeks)

If you don't have a bench I'd highly recommend getting one, you can get an adjustable one for about $70 these days.